# Android: CardView Coming On Action Bar

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-actionbar, android-cardview

I have used recycler View to display CardView. I have done this in the navigation drawer Main Activity. But my card View is being displayed on Action Bar.

app_bar_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android=
"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="kb.niranjan.tvseries.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

content_menu

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cv"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
android:layout_margin="08dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#263238"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="06dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:id="@+id/person_photo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/person_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/person_age"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I want to display my cards below ActionBar

Comment: I found a solution for it. Add a toolbar explicitly and use noactionbar as your theme

Answer (score 2):

Change your `app_bar_main`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=
    "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First add include layout id: For Example

```
<include  android:id="@+id/card_layout layout="@layout/content_main" />"
```

and in Toolbar add **layout_above**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_above="@+id/card_layout"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```